# Is there a way to split json data from a file in powershell?

Tags: json, powershell, replace, split

I am reading data from a json file via **powershell**, with the ultimate goal of updating said file. I need to split the data in a chunk I want to keep and a chunk I want to update, and to complicate the matter further, the place where I need to split the text varies throughout a foreach-loop, thus I need that part to come from a variable.

I have tried `.split/-split` and `.replace/-replace` in numerous configurations, but it seems this is harder than one would assume in **powershell**.

All the below files in the same folder.

**Json (json.json):**

```
{
  "Section1": {
    "Heading1": [
      "Thing1",
      "Thing2"
    ]
  },
  "Section2": [
    "Thing1",
    "Thing2"
  ]
}
```

**Powershell (powershell.ps1):**

```
$originalJsonString = Get-Content -Path ".\json.json"
$SplitTarget = "Section2"

$JsonString = {This is the part that I am iffy about}

Write-Output $JsonString
```

**The output I want from the above would be**

```
{
"Section1": {
    "Heading1": [
        "Thing1",
        "Thing2"
    ]
},
```

I have tried just about everything I can think of in relation to split and replace, but yet the solution alludes me.
Note in the solution above, that it is an important factor that `$originalJsonString` is split (or whatever) by $SplitTarget, and not "Section2", as that is also a factor in my equation.

This is my first time asking, so if I am doing something wrong I apologise.

Thank you.

Edit:
It is only fair that I add the reason I don't convert to an object.
The syntax which powershell exports when converting json to an object and back is undesirable for my use.
However, if using an object is the ONLY way, and slitting is out of the question, then another solution must be found.
Thank you.

Edit:
If objects was the way to go, I ended up finding a way more complicated way to format the .json the way I wanted it.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: You could fiddle around with `-split` regexes, but really the only reliable way IMO is converting to object. After all... JSON **is** JavaScript Object Notation.

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is read the json file in using :

```
$json = Get-Content .\json.json -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
```

I faked that here using a 'here-string':

```
$json = @"
{
    "Section1": {
        "Heading1": [
            "Thing1",
            "Thing2"
        ]
    },
    "Section2": [
        "Thing1",
        "Thing2"
    ]
}
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Next, define what you want to keep or update:

```
$sectionToKeep   = "Section1"
$sectionToUpdate = "Section2"
```

To see what is in there use `$json.$sectionToKeep | ConvertTo-Json`

> ```
> {
>     "Heading1":  [
>                      "Thing1",
>                      "Thing2"
>                  ]
> }
> ```

Next, update $section2 leaving everything else untouched. I am writing an object that stores an array, just like in `$sectionToKeep`:

```
$json.$sectionToUpdate = @{'Heading2' = 'Thing3', 'Thing4'}
```

and finally output (or write back to file) the new complete json:

```
$json | ConvertTo-Json
```

Using your example gives you this:

> ```
> {
>     "Section1":  {
>                      "Heading1":  [
>                                       "Thing1",
>                                       "Thing2"
>                                   ]
>                  },
>     "Section2":  {
>                      "Heading2":  [
>                                       "Thing3",
>                                       "Thing4"
>                                   ]
>                  }
> }
> ```

Hope that helps

Comment: You are correct, my json was bad.
I'll be sure to fix it right away, thank you.
Edit: Someone already did ;P

Comment: @Graesholt. Well done. I have removed that remark from the answer

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to really understand your question, but I would convert the Json to an object and then filter the sub data and create a file again

```
$obj = Get-Content json.json -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to just isolate a section and create a new json file, then you can use the following:

```
$file = Get-Content .\json.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$file | Select-Object Section1 | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content New.json
```